# NSOperation dependent operation and dependent objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsoperation

I have two different `NSOperation` subclasses. One that downloads the feed from server and the other one to parse.

```
@interface FeedDownloader:NSOperation
 @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *downloadedFeed;
@end

@interface FeedParser:NSOperation
 @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *feedToParse;
@end
```

Then, in my "view controller", I add these operations to my `NSOperationQueue` and set dependency.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
FeedDownloader *downloader = [[FeedDownloader alloc] init];
FeedParser *parser = [[FeedParser alloc] init];
[parser addDependency:downloader];
[downloader addObserver:self forKeypath: @"isFinished" context:kDownloaderContext];
[queue addOperation:downloader];
[queue addOperation:parser];
```

Now, I get the "KVO notification" from the downloader that it finished downloading the feed. How could I pass the downloaded feed to the parser once the download completes and before it starts parsing.

Answer (score 1):

In your `FeedParser` class you can ensure the the `isReady` is not true until it has the required data is set - this way the operation won't prematurely start until it has it's dependencies.

There are lots of ways to do this - the first thing that would come to mind for me is to use the completion block of the download operation

```
__weak __typeof(parser)     weakParser     = parser;
downloader.completionBlock = ^{
  weakParser.feedToParse = downloader.downloadedFeed;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a protocol, maybe `FeedProvider`, which has a method by which a `FeedParser` can request a feed string. Make `FeedDownloader` adopt `FeedProvider`. Give `FeedParser` a `provider` property of type `id <FeedProvider>`. At creation time, give the `parser` object a reference to the `downloader` object as its provider.